# Can I specify the sign of a coefficient in sem model?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

Say there is a sem model that I would like to explore:

```
model.hobbie <- specifyModel()
Sport -> LoveSport, L1, NA 
Sport -> HateSport, L2, NA
Read -> LoveRead, L3, NA
Read -> HateRead, L4, NA    
....
#
```

And the following is a sample results

```
L1    -0.88687557 0.080602135 -11.0031275 3.691040e-28 LoveSport <--- Sport      
L2     0.74943624 0.084997523   8.8171538 1.174059e-18 HateSport <--- Sport      
L3     0.74410012 0.089358029   8.3271769 8.279299e-17 LoveRead <--- Read      
L4    -0.76273556 0.089643657  -8.5085279 1.761555e-17 HateRead <--- Read  
....
```

Initiative it would be easier for positive emotion be assigned with a positive coefficient, plus now all the path output for Sport are in the opposite sign of others which made reading the output very difficult.

I understand I can flip the sign manually when I report it, but can I write something in the model to specify the sign of LoveSport to positive?

this is a very similar question to [How to specify/restrict the sign of coefficients in a GLM or similar model in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73662/how-to-specify-restrict-the-sign-of-coefficients-in-a-glm-or-similar-model-in-r)

But the solution was in Lavaan. I tried to read the sem manual but I fail to find any information on restricting the sign...

Comment: It's not a guarantee, but if you give the model starting values that are close to the value, in the direction you want, it usually works. I think you use the startvalues() function for this in sem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JeremyMiles, I tried assign startvalues by replacing the above line "Sport -> LoveSport, L1, NA" to "Sport -> LoveSport, L1, 0.8" but that doesn't work.  Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: I think that constrains a value in sem, it doesn't give it a starting value.

Comment: @JeremyMiles, it says "start value for  a free parameter or value of a fixed parameter" in the ? page... I thought LoverSport is a free parameter.. how should I assign a startvalue? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, OK. What do you mean by 'it didn't work'?

Comment: @JeremyMiles, the output stay the same with a negative coefficient... so it seems assigning 0.8 doesn't work.

Comment: You might need to assign more of the laodings to the value that you want. Also, sem might constrain some loadings to 1.00 automatically, when you want them to be -1.00.